# Android Databinding Error for Multiple Layout files

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, indexoutofboundsexception, android-databinding

I am getting an error on using with android datat binding librery
i have successfully compleated one layout it working.
but i created new layout and add `<layout>` tag in new `.xml` and `Build->clean project` then getting an error

```
* What went wrong:  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

**my build.gradle module level**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "codingwithmitch.com.databindinggettingstarted"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

**Gradle wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6- 
all.zip
```

**Gradle propertie**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IMainActivity {
//DataBinding
ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

//Var
private Product mProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    Products mProducts = new Products();
    mProduct = mProducts.PRODUCTS[10];
    mBinding.setProduct(mProduct);
    mBinding.setQuantity(1);
    mBinding.setIMainActivity(this);
    mBinding.setTestImageUrl(String.valueOf(mProduct.getImage()));
}

@Override
public void inflateQuantityDialog() {
    ChooseQuantityDialog dialog = new ChooseQuantityDialog();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.dialog_choose_quantity));
}

@Override
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    mBinding.setQuantity(quantity);
}

@Override
public void addToCart() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <data>
    <import type="codingwithmitch.com.databindinggettingstarted.util.StringUtil" />
    <import type="codingwithmitch.com.databindinggettingstarted.util.BigDecimalUtil" />
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
      name="product"
      type="codingwithmitch.com.databindinggettingstarted.models.Product" />
    <variable
      name="quantity"
      type="int" />
    <variable
      name="iMainActivity"
      type="codingwithmitch.com.databindinggettingstarted.interfaces.IMainActivity" />
    <variable
      name="testImageUrl"
      type="String" />
  </data>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:background="@color/White">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="10sp"
          android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"
          android:text="@{StringUtil.convertIntToString(product.num_ratings)}"
          android:id="@+id/num_ratings"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


        <RatingBar
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="?attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
          android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
          android:scaleX="1.2"
          android:scaleY="1.2"
          android:numStars="5"
          android:rating="@{BigDecimalUtil.getFloat(product.rating)}"
          android:id="@+id/rating"
          android:isIndicator="true"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/num_ratings"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

      </RelativeLayout>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:text="@{product.title}"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <ImageView
          app:imageUrl="@{product.image}"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:id="@+id/image" />

      </RelativeLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="14sp"
          android:layout_height="14sp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_dollor_sign_red" />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@{product.hasSalePrice() ? BigDecimalUtil.getValue(product.sale_price) : BigDecimalUtil.getValue(product.price)}"
          android:textColor="@color/red2"
          android:textSize="16sp" />


        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/original_price"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/strike_through"
          android:text="@{BigDecimalUtil.getValue(product.price)}"
          android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"
          android:textSize="10sp"
          android:visibility="@{product.hasSalePrice()? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}" />

      </LinearLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
        android:onClick="@{()-> iMainActivity.inflateQuantityDialog()}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/quantity_button">


        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textColor="@color/Black"
          android:text="@{StringUtil.getQuantityString(quantity)}"
          android:id="@+id/quantity" />

        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="14dp"
          android:layout_height="15dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quantity"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_up_down_arrows" />


      </RelativeLayout>


      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_rounded_button"
        android:onClick="@{()->iMainActivity.addToCart()}"
        android:id="@+id/add_to_cart">

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textColor="@color/Black"
          android:text="Add to cart"
          android:contentDescription="@{product.title ?? product.description}"
          android:id="@+id/text_add_to_cart"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


      </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

**IMainActivity**
public interface IMainActivity {

```
void inflateQuantityDialog();

void setQuantity(int quantity);

void addToCart();
```

}

this code everythings ok,bt i just create .xml file and add `<layout>` tag and cleab project ,error occuring.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_background">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_button"
      android:padding="5dp">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/dialog_quantity_title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Could you post new `.xml` layout here?

Comment: `<layout>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_background"> </LinearLayout>
</layout>`                                                                                                               **No any other code ,i just add `layout` tag in new xml**

Comment: Does your layout has closed tag </layout>? By the way, you can modify question (add layout and other stuff)

Comment: ok,i edited my code,this class from gitub ,it work properly.bt i cant create new layout with data binding.

Comment: Try use `<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` instead of <layout> - problem with namespace resolving

Comment: does it solve problem?

Comment: Show code where you are using products.PRODUCTS.

Comment: @ConstOrVar Problem not solved,can i add just `<layout>` tag with name space in xml file,i just do that,no other data binding functions like `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @ Khemraj i just following [https://github.com/mitchtabian/DataBindingGettingStarted] this project with [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4XO_y3RErI] this video tutorial.it compleatly clear.but i just create new xml file and add databinding tags it getting error while clear or rebuild

Comment: I am suffering the same problem.It seems its an encoding problem which only occurs in windows machine.You run same project in linux or mac..works like charm.

Comment: Thanks for replay, bt i am using windows machine .how can i solve this problem